# Metódo retornando NullPointerException (JAVA)

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo um exercício orientado a objetos, tenho um objeto Carro e um objeto Motorista, quando tento atribuir a String nome a um dos objetos esta me retornando um Null

```
    public class Motorista {
            String nome;
            Carro CarroAtual;
    //Construtor   
        public Motorista(String nome)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
    //Método
            public void entrarNoCarro(Carro carro){

            if(carro.motoristaAtual == null){       
            CarroAtual.motoristaAtual.nome = getNome();
            CarroAtual.nome = carro.getNome();
            System.out.println("O motorista " + nome + " entrou no carro " + carro.nome + ".");
        }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Este carro já tem um motorista.");
        }
            if(carro.velocidade != 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("O motorista não pode entrar em um carro em movimento");
            }
        }
```

Error se encontra na linha `CarroAtual.motoristaAtual.nome = getNome();`

Código completo ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Classe Motorista

```
    public class Motorista {
        String nome;
        Carro CarroAtual;
//Construtor   
    public Motorista(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
//Métodos    
    public void entrarNoCarro(Carro carro)
    {        
        if(carro.motoristaAtual == null){   
        CarroAtual.motoristaAtual.nome = getNome();
        CarroAtual.nome = carro.getNome();
        System.out.println("O motorista " + nome + " entrou no carro " + carro.nome + ".");
    }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Este carro já tem um motorista.");
    }
        if(carro.velocidade != 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O motorista não pode entrar em um carro em movimento");
        }
    }
    public void sairDoCarro(){
        if (CarroAtual.nome == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Não há um motorista para sair do carro");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("O motorista" + nome + "saiu do carro");
        }
        if(CarroAtual.velocidade != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O motorista não pode sair de um carro em movimento.");
        }

}
    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }
    public String toString() { 
        if(CarroAtual.nome != null) {
            return getNome() + CarroAtual.posicaoX + CarroAtual.posicaoY + CarroAtual.velocidade + CarroAtual.aceleracao;
        }
        else {
          return getNome() + CarroAtual.posicaoX + CarroAtual.posicaoY + CarroAtual.velocidade + CarroAtual.aceleracao; 
        }
    }  
}
```

Classe Carro

```
    public class Carro {  
    String nome;
    int direcao = 0;
    int velocidade = 0;
    int aceleracao = 0;
    int posicaoX = 0;
    int posicaoY = 0;
    Motorista motoristaAtual;
//Construtores           
    public Carro(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public Carro(String nome, int posicaoX, int posicaoY) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.posicaoX = posicaoX;
        this.posicaoY = posicaoY;
    }
//Métodos    
    public void mover(){
        try {
        if(motoristaAtual.getNome() != null){

        System.out.println("O carro " + nome + " começou a se mover.");
    }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O carro não pode se mover sem um motorista.");
        }
    }
        catch (Exception a) {
            System.out.println(a.getMessage());
        }
    }
    boolean mover(boolean progressivo){
    if(velocidade == 0 && direcao > 0 && motoristaAtual.nome != null){
        direcao = direcao + (+direcao) + (+direcao);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

    }
    public void acelerar(int incremento) {
        try {
            if(mover(true)) {
                aceleracao = aceleracao + incremento;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }               
    }
    public void frear(int decremento) {
        try {
            mover();
            aceleracao = aceleracao - decremento;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }               
    }   
    public void virarAEsquerda() {
        posicaoX = posicaoX - 90;
    }
    public void virarADireita() {
        posicaoX = posicaoX + 90;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }
    public int getVelocidade() {
        return this.velocidade;
    }
    public int getAceleracao() {
        return this.aceleracao;
    }
    public int getPosicaoX() {
        return this.posicaoX;
    }
    public int getPosicaoY() {
        return this.posicaoY;
    }
    public String toString() {
        if (motoristaAtual != null) {
        return (motoristaAtual.getNome()) + posicaoX + posicaoY + velocidade + aceleracao;
        }
        else {
            return nome + posicaoX + posicaoY + velocidade + aceleracao; 
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Carro c1 = new Carro("C1");
        Motorista m1 = new Motorista("M1");
        m1.entrarNoCarro(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: if(carro.motoristaAtual == null) se entrou dentro do if a variável está a null e como está a tentar aceder ao nome do motoristaAtual dá esse erro

Comment: Não entendi, como eu poderia resolver?

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/394556/edit) a questão e mostre como está a instanciar os objetos no método Main por favor, assim poderei incluir uma resposta mais completa.
Também acrescente a definição da classe Carro.

Comment: Editado..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema, tal como descrevi em comentário está na não instanciação do campo `motoristaAtual` e mais tarde tentativa de atribuição de um **nome** a esse **motorista**, mas como este motorista não está instanciado ele tem o valor de `Null`.

**A sua versão:**

```
public void entrarNoCarro(Carro carro){

            if(carro.motoristaAtual == null){       
            CarroAtual.motoristaAtual.nome = getNome(); //CarroAtual é null neste momento.
            CarroAtual.nome = carro.getNome(); // Se afetar CarroAtual com carro ambos são o mesmo objeto e não é necessário atribuição do nome.
            System.out.println("O motorista " + nome + " entrou no carro " + carro.nome + ".");
        }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Este carro já tem um motorista.");
        }
            if(carro.velocidade != 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("O motorista não pode entrar em um carro em movimento");
            }
        }
```

**A minha versão:**

```
public void entrarNoCarro(Carro carro)
    {        
        if(carro.motoristaAtual == null){
            CarroAtual = carro; // o CarroAtual to motorista é o carro onde entrou
            CarroAtual.motoristaAtual = this; // O Motorista deste carro é o Motorista que entrou no carro
            System.out.println("O motorista " + nome + " entrou no carro " + carro.nome + ".");
    }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Este carro já tem um motorista.");
    }
        if(carro.velocidade != 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O motorista não pode entrar em um carro em movimento");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Precisa instanciar a classe Carro
ex:

public Motorista(String nome){
 carroAtual = new Carro();

}

Comment: Pelo o que eu notei você não instanciou a classe motorista dentro do carro e está chamando o método sem instanciar, tente dar um System.out.println(CarroAtual.motoristaAtual), para verificar se retorna nulo.